# Do you know an effective algorithm for mapping the tree structure to a table representation

Tags: algorithm

Do you know an effective algorithm for mapping the tree structure to a table representation and back?
The problem reduces to writing a function to get the node object from the X,Y coordinates. *(Look at the pictures)* New nodes can be added and removed. Do you have any ideas?

An example of my structure: 
[image: An example of my structure]
An example of how I want to map a structure to a table:
[image: An example of how I want to map a structure to a table]

Comment: Why did you choose such a table representation? Such a representation is not easily generated or parsed by an algorithm. Only a human reader takes benefit from it - and a human user has more benefit from the tree representation. So please tell us if you only want to map to a table or to a table of exactly this design.

Comment: This table view is a business-task--oriented element of the user interface. In this business problem, the tree view is not the best.

Comment: Add your current approach. Maybe you want to start with depth first search and enumerating the nodes in post-order.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a table with the following structure to represent a tree:

- id - primary key
- value - some value for the node
- parent_id - the reference to the parent

**Building the tree from the table:**

If the parent id is empty you know this is the root node. You can then scan the table for all nodes with the parent_id corresponding to the root node, to find its children. You can then do the same recursively with the children of the children of the root node and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I just ran into the same problem. In my case, I needed to generate a tree structure for presentation purposes from a set of columns in a database. Since the columns used for this needed to be selectable at run-time, any sort of fixed table structure was out of the question.

I came up with the following algorithm (C# 10) to create the tree structure.
It's not as efficient as it could be; it's kind of a brute-force approach and there's room for improvement. I assumed that all the fields in the table are strings and that the table might be jagged, that is the right-most values in each row may be `null` values.

To Use it you create a `CollectionTreeBuilder` object and then repeatedly call the `AddRecord` member with each record in your table. Once that's done the `Root` property will contain the corresponding tree structure.

Going from a tree to a table representation is pretty simple. You traverse the tree recursively and output a row at each leaf node. The `CollectionNode.ToString` method is a good example of this. It generates an S-Expression style string (great for unit testing) but could be modified to generate some other format.

```cs
public class CollectionNode {
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<string> Key { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<CollectionNode>? Children { get; set; } = null;

    public override string ToString() =>
        Children == null
            ? $"({Value})"
            : $"({Value} {Children.Aggregate("", (a, b) => a.ToString() + b.ToString())})";
}

public class CollectionTreeBuilder {
    public void AddRecord(IEnumerable<string?> record) {
        var current = Root;
        var key = new List<String> { };
        foreach (var value in record.TakeWhile(v => v != null)) {
            if (current.Children == null)
                current.Children = new List<CollectionNode> { };
            var child = current.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == value);
            if (child == null) {
                current.Children.Add(new CollectionNode { Value = value! });
                current = current.Children.Last();
            } else {
                current = child;
            }
            key.Add(value!);
        }
        current.Key = key;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Root.ToString();

    public CollectionNode Root { get; private set; } = new CollectionNode { Value = "root" };
}
```